# Google+ sign in without google+ profile

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, google-play-services

According to this post:
http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2013/12/google-sign-in-improvements11.html

And this excerpt:

> https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#all-users
> Google+ Sign-In provides support for all users with a Google account, even if they have not yet created a Google+ profile. Your app can use the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login scope or the basic profile scope: [...]
>
> profile scope - Adding the Google+ Sign-In button with the profile scope provides a simple, secure way to authenticate users with access to only the user's basic information. Users are not prompted to create a Google+ profile.

I gather that it is no longer required to have a google+ account to use the google+ OATH2.0 authentication google is pushing on, great! However when I use the example with this code fragment:

```
 GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API, null)
    .addScope(new Scope("profile"))
    .build();
```

it still asks me to 'upgrade' my account to google+ which I don't want to force my users to.

Can anyone help me what I need to change in this example? I've tried different scopes with the same outcome. A different API I couldn't find (and shouldn't be necessary).

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_4_initialize_the_googleapiclient) adding a scope should look more like this: `addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PROFILE)`. I'm not familiar enough with Java to know if there is actually a difference.

Comment: @abraham Thanks for your reply. I tried that scope too; I think it is a constant for `new Scope("profile")` the result is the same. With that scope I get a "create a profile" prompt too.

Comment: @Nebula were you ever able to come to a resolution?

Comment: @Billy From what I recall this was actually a bug. I think they fixed it too, but I can't verify it right now. Are you facing the same issue?